# What are the Sitecore Next.jss security recommendations for PUT and DELETE HTTP Methods Accepted?

Tags: jss, security, nextjs

We recently received recommendation that one of the Next.jss sites can be accessed via the URL https://yoursiteurl/**sitecore**.

As part of the Sitecore Next.jss setup, we keep the Sitecore folder at root for all the configuration; the recommendation is to disable the PUT and DELETE methods for all paths and systems.

In this scenario, the Next.js application is deployed into the Azure webapps. Any suggestions to disallow the PUT and DELETE to comply with this recommendation?

Comment: Why do you have a `/sitecore` folder in your next.js application?

Comment: What is the use of /sitecore folder and you can add security and allow only restricted access or at firewall redirect direct call to this folder to home page or 404 page.